# Ayuda para agregar una opcion a un menu

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola buenas noches o madrugadas. Podran ayudarme se que a lo mejor es algo obvio pero me falta añadirle la opcion 5 a mi programa pero no se me ocurre como hacerle. Ayuda por favor.

Este es el codigo, ya le puse la opcion Mostar tope pero no se que hacer ya:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct nodo
{
    int numero;
    struct nodo *siguiente;
};

typedef nodo *ptrPila;

void imprimir (ptrPila);
void eliminaPila (ptrPila &);
void push (ptrPila &, int);
int pop (ptrPila &);
void mostrartope (ptrPila &)

int main()
{
    ptrPila p=NULL;
    int opcion,n;
    do
    {
        cout<<endl<<"\tImplementacion de una Pila"<<endl;




        cout<<"1) Apilar" <<endl;
        cout<<"2) Desapilar" <<endl;
        cout<<"3) Ver Pila" <<endl;
        cout<<"4) Destruir Pila" <<endl;
        cout<<"5) Mostrar Tope" <<endl;
        cout<<"6) Salir" <<endl;
        cout<<"Elegir una Opcion"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;

        switch(opcion)

        {
        case 1: cout<<"Aplicar valor:";cin>>n;
        push (p,n);
        break;

        case 2: if(p !=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Valor Eliminado";
            n=pop(p);
            cout<<n<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout<<"Pila vacia"<<endl;
        break;

        case 3: cout<<"Contenido de pila:"<<endl;
        imprimir (p);
        break;

        case 4: eliminaPila (p);
        cout<<"Pila destruida"<<endl;
        break;

        case 5: cout<<"Mostrar tope:"; cin>>n;
        imprimir (n);
        break;

    }
} while (opcion !=6);
return 0;
}

void push(ptrPila &p, int n)
{
    ptrPila q = new (struct nodo);
    q->numero =n;
    q->siguiente =p;
    p = q;
}

int pop (ptrPila &p)
{
    int n = p->numero;
    ptrPila q=p;
    p=p->siguiente;
    delete(q);
    return n;
}

void eliminaPila (ptrPila &p)
{
    ptrPila q;

    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        q=p;
        p=p->siguiente;
        delete(q);
    }
}

void imprimir(ptrPila p)
{
    while (p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->numero<<endl;
        p=p->siguiente;
    }
    cout<<endl;

void mostartope 
}
```

Comment: Es sobre el tema de pilas.

Comment: Hola buenas noches. No puedo compilar la imagen ¿podrías poner el código que estás usando para que lo pueda probar?

Comment: Hola Ricardo, por favor, lee la sección [ask] para aprender más sobre cómo formular tu pregunta. Las preguntas que incluyen un [mcve] siempre son mejor recibidas.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que este es el código que estás usando? Lo digo porque no compila.

Comment: No compila por que tiene void mostartope (tpr pila 4$) y no se que hacer. Lo que quiero es que el programa me muestre el tope de la pila cuando le de la opcion mostar pila

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente te cuesta ver lo que tienes que hacer porque tu programa es algo confuso. Voy a aconsejarte algunas cosas para mejorar la legibilidad.

#### En C++, `struct` no forma parte del tipo.

En el lenguaje C, es necesario anteponer `struct` antes del nombre de una estructura, porque `struct` forma parte del tipo de datos, pero en C++ esto no es así, por lo tanto puedes cambiar tu declaración de nodo a:

```
struct nodo
{
    int numero;
    nodo *siguiente; // No lleva 'struct' antes de 'nodo'.
};
```

#### Confundes nodos con pilas.

Una de las primeras cosas que haces con tu tipo `nodo` es crear un alias a puntero del mismo:

```
typedef nodo *ptrPila;
```

El problema es que llamas el puntero a nodo como puntero a pila y un nodo no es una pila... es como si dijeras que un escalón es una escalera: las escaleras están hechas de escalones pero los escalones no son escaleras. Te aconsejo que declares un objeto `Pila` que maneje los nodos.

#### Un objeto `Pila`.

Tu `Pila` puede contener todas las funciones que has definido sueltas:

```
struct Pila
{
    void imprimir ();
    void eliminaPila ();
    void push (int);
    int pop ();
    void mostrartope ()

private:
    nodo *tope = nullptr; // el tope de la pila.
};
```

Si te fijas, he eliminado todos los parámetros de tipo `ptrPila` de las funciones, simplemente porque la pila ya almacena el nodo y por lo tanto no necesita recibirlo como parámetro.

#### Las definiciones cambian ligeramente.

Ahora las funciones pertenecen al objeto `Pila`, y no reciben un nodo externo si no que usan el que pertenece a la función, así que las definiciones cambiarán también:

```
//   vvvvvv <--- La funcion push pertenece a Pila
void Pila::push(int n)
{
    nodo *nuevo_nodo = new nodo; // No lleva 'struct' antes de 'nodo'.
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^ <--- El nombre 'nuevo_nodo' es mas claro que 'q'.

    nuevo_nodo->numero =n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente =tope;
    //                     ^^^^ <--- Usamos el nodo tope, no uno que recibimos por parametros
    tope = nuevo_nodo;
}
```

No necesitas poner `struct` antes de un tipo estructura porque estamos en C++. Evita los nombres de una sola letra, porque son confusos. Este algoritmo de apilar datos va poniendo nodos *debajo* del nodo tope:
[image]

```
//  vvvvvv <--- La funcion pop pertenece a Pila
int Pila::pop ()
{
    int n = 0;
    //      ^^^^ <--- Usamos el nodo tope, no uno que recibimos por parametro
    if (nodo *antiguo_tope = tope)
    //        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- El nombre 'antiguo_tope' es mas claro que 'q'.
    {
        tope = antiguo_tope->siguiente
        n = antiguo_tope->numero;
        delete antiguo_tope; // delete no es una funcion, no requiere parentesis
    }

    return n;
}
```

Tu algoritmo de desapilar mueve el tope una posición hacia abajo y borra el antiguo tope. No uses paréntesis para llamar a `delete` porque es un operador no una función. Desapila solo si el tope no es un puntero nulo.

```
//   vvvvvv <--- La funcion eliminaPila pertenece a Pila
void Pila::eliminaPila ()
{
    //    vvvv <--- El 'tope' de esta pila.
    while(tope!=nullptr)
    //          ^^^^^^^ <-- nullptr es el literal de puntero nulo de C++
    {
        pop(); // Ya tienes una funcion que borra el tope de la pila, usala.
    }
}
```

En C++ no se usa la macro `NULL` para referirse a un puntero nulo, se usa el literal `nullptr` que es más adecuado. Por otro lado no necesitas duplicar la lógica de borrado de nodos pues ya la tienes implementada en la función de desapilar, ve desapilando datos hasta que la pila esté vacía.

```
//   vvvvvv <--- La funcion imprimir pertenece a Pila
void Pila::imprimir()
{
    for (nodo *actual = tope; actual != nullptr; actual = actual->siguiente)
    {
        cout<<actual->numero<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Recuerda, no uses nombres de una sola letra, es confuso. Cambia `NULL` por `nullptr`. Y tu función de `mostartope`, pues es tan sencillo (con los nombres adecuados) como mostrar el tope:

```
//   vvvvvv <--- La funcion imprimir pertenece a Pila
void Pila::mostartope()
{
    cout << tope->numero << endl;
}
```

#### Conclusión.

No estabas entendiendo tu algoritmo, siempre tuviste el tope de tu pila a la vista.