# Advertencia con listas en c “warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, lista

El programa complila pero tira la siguiente advertencia

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

y no entiendo por qué.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} Nodo;

typedef Nodo *list;
typedef Nodo *pnodo;

//Nodo *inicio,*inicio2,*ultimo,*ultimo2;

void agregar_lista1(list *inicio,list *ultimo);
void agregar_lista2(list *inicio2,list *ultimo2);
void mostrar_lista(list *inicio);

int main ()
{
    int op;
    list inicio = NULL,inicio2 = NULL,ultimo = NULL,ultimo2 = NULL;
    do
    {
        printf ("MENU");
        printf ("\nOp1 Ingresar nodo en la lista 1");
        printf ("\nOp2 Ingresar nodo en la lista 2");
        printf ("\nOp3 Mostar los datos almacenados en la lista");
        printf ("\nOp4 Mostrar suma de las listas anteriores\n\n");
        scanf ("%d",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
        case 1:
            agregar_lista1(&inicio,&ultimo);
            break;
        case 2:
            agregar_lista1(&inicio2,&ultimo2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mostrar_lista(&inicio);
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        }
    }
    while (op!=4);

    return 0;
}

void agregar_lista1(list *inicio,list *ultimo)
{
    Nodo *nuevo;
    nuevo = malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    if (nuevo==NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nNo se pudo crear el nodo\n");
    }

    printf ("Ingrese un numero entero positivo: ");
    scanf ("%d",&nuevo->dato);

    if (inicio == NULL)
    {
        nuevo->siguiente = (*inicio);
        *inicio = nuevo;
        *ultimo  = nuevo;
    }
    else
    {
        /* en la linea de abajo es donde me da el error */
        (*ultimo)->siguiente = nuevo;
        *ultimo = nuevo;
        nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
    }
}

void mostrar_lista(list *inicio)
{
    pnodo ptr;
    ptr = *inicio;
    if (inicio != NULL)
    {
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            printf ("\nDato %d \n",ptr->dato);
            ptr = ptr->siguiente;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n\nLa lista esta vacia\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: La definición de mostrar_lista arriba y la implementación abajo no coinciden. En la definición no tiene parámetros y en la implementación sí. Además, si recibe un list*, no le puedes pasar la variable inicio en la llamada que haces en el switch porque inicio es del tipo list y no del tipo list*. Además, tienes definida una función agregar_lista2 que luego ni llamas ni implementas. No me he parado a revisar el resto del código, pero el warning parece que es por cómo llamas a mostrar_lista.

Answer (score 2):

El lenguaje C es sensitivo a mayúsculas y minúsculas. Dentro de tu definición de `nodo` estás creando un tipo nuevo llamado `Nodo`:

```
 typedef struct nodo
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Tipo 'struct nodo';
 {
     int dato;
     struct Nodo *siguiente;
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Puntero a un TIPO NUEVO que es 'struct Nodo'.
 } Nodo;
// ^^^^ <--- Alias de 'nodo' llamado 'Nodo'.
```

Cambia tu definición para que el tipo interno `struct Nodo` coincida con el nombre de tu tipo externo:

```
typedef struct Nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} Nodo;
```

#### Problemas adicionales en tu código.

A parte de [lo mencionado en comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287614/advertencia-con-listas-en-c-warning-assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type#comment528075_287614) por SuperG280, tu código tiene un fallo que es especialmente molesto y recurrente en el sitio StackOverflow.

Estás creando un Nodo de datos que se usará como parte de una lista simplemente enlazada y renombras un puntero a ese nodo como `lista`. **Mal hecho**, eso es tan disparatado como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

Un Nodo es un Nodo no una Lista, así que no deberías llamar `lista` a un puntero a `Nodo`. Esta confusión [ha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154684/reemplazar-un-nodo-arbol-busqueda-binaria/154863?r=SearchResults&s=1|36.8881#154863) [su](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111434/no-se-imprimen-bien-las-listas-doblemente-enlazadas/111517?r=SearchResults&s=3|27.7388#111517)[c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116811/concatenar-dos-listas-simplemente-enlazadas/116952?r=SearchResults&s=4|24.7505#116952)[e](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203326/listas-dobles-c/203412?r=SearchResults&s=5|24.5789#203412)[di](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110921/ayuda-para-agregar-una-opcion-a-un-menu/111337?r=SearchResults&s=6|23.5861#111337)[do](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167430/como-lleno-una-multilista/167673?r=SearchResults&s=7|23.3225#167673) [m](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274471/duda-sobre-el-uso-de-pilas-en-c/274556?r=SearchResults&s=8|23.1658#274556)[o](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120913/algo-no-funciona-en-mi-implementaci%c3%b3n-de-listas-abiertas/121126?r=SearchResults&s=9|21.0174#121126)[nt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169453/tengo-una-lista-simplemente-enlazada-c%c3%b3mo-le-a%c3%b1ado-datos/169454?r=SearchResults&s=10|19.8107#169454)[on](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240773/c%c3%b3mo-eliminar-elementos-de-una-pila-conservando-los-nodos-anteriores-en-c/241064?r=SearchResults&s=11|17.1387#241064)[e](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/204421/segmentation-fault-c/204704?r=SearchResults&s=12|16.1643#204704)[s](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115391/asignaci%c3%b3n-de-punteros-en-listas-enlazadas/115649?r=SearchResults&s=13|16.1643#115649) [de](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192263/warning-passing-argument-1-of-hashinsertar-from-incompatible-pointer-type/192403?r=SearchResults&s=14|16.0540#192403) [ve](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170266/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-definir-el-nodo-ra%c3%adz-de-un-%c3%81rbol/170358?r=SearchResults&s=15|13.1530#170358)[ce](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205348/como-extraigo-datos-del-final-de-una-pila-dinamica/205388?r=SearchResults&s=16|12.5045#205388)[s](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150674/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mostrar-%c3%banicamente-n%c3%bameros-que-no-se-repitan-de-un-archivo-con-c/150775?r=SearchResults&s=17|12.4209#150775) y no para de suceder una y otra vez. El problema que provoca no llamar las cosas por su nombre es que el código se hace difícil de entender, de seguir, de depurar y de compartir. Te aconsejo que cambies por completo tu aproximación creando un objeto Lista que contenga Nodos:

```
typedef struct Nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} Nodo;

typedef struct Lista
{
    Nodo *raiz;
} Lista;
```

Comment: Pongo opción 1 (1 Ingresar nodo en la lista 1) y solo deja poner un solo número.

Answer (score 0):

Acabé de ver el código, hay varias fallas.
En este prototipo:

```
void agregar_lista1(list *inicio,list *ultimo);
```

El primer parámetro de la función recibe la dirección de memoria de un puntero; sin embargo, tu haces esto:

```
if (inicio == NULL) //Error lógico
{
```

Lo que estás comparando ahí, es lo que tiene guardado el puntero a puntero y no debería ser de esa manera. Ya que el puntero doble "inicio" tiene la dirección de memoria del puntero que pasaste como referencia y es evidente que esa condición no será igual a NULL y por esa razón, el caso contrario se cumplirá y ahí es donde viene el inconveniente:

```
else
{
   /* en la linea de abajo es donde me da el error */
   (*ultimo)->siguiente = nuevo;
   *ultimo = nuevo;
   nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
}
```

Como no existe ningún Nodo inicial, se está tratando de acceder a la dirección 0x00 y desde ahí, el programa se bloquea.

```
(*ultimo)->siguiente = nuevo;
```

La solución es cambiar la condición por esta:

```
if (*inicio == NULL)
{
    nuevo->siguiente = (*inicio);
    *inicio = nuevo;
    *ultimo  = nuevo;
}
```

Con *inicio, se accede al contenido de la dirección de memoria que pasaste por referencia y de ese modo, el resultado de esa condición será verdadera.
El mismo problema tienes en la función "mostrar_lista", debes cambiar la condición a esta:

```
void mostrar_lista(list *inicio)
{
    pnodo ptr;
    ptr = *inicio;
    if (*inicio != NULL) //aquí faltó el asterisco 
    {
```

Comment: Ahora cuando apreto 1 para ingresar números a la lista, dice "Ingrese un numero entero positivo: ", per cuando ingreso me vuelve a mostrar el menú.

Comment: Te va mostrar el menú, porqué no estás pausando el programa. Es decir, cada vez que el usuario ingrese un valor, debería pausarlo, de ese modo, no saldrá de una vez el menú.

Comment: Pauso después del scanf y queda con el cursor esperando.